# how to stub returned object from function to deal with any future method calls from that object

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, sinon, stub, spy

I have a typescript application where I have the following two lines of code:

```
    const obj = await getCredentials(name, role);

    await obj.getPromise();
```

`getCredentials` has a return type of `Promise<AWS.ChainableTemporaryCredentials>` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ChainableTemporaryCredentials.html), thus making obj of type AWS.ChainableTemporaryCredentials. In writing a unit test this code, I have included a line `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` and used JSON.parse on this string (representing the obj object) to make a stub for the `getCredentials` method. The stub looks like the following (note I cannot show the value due to workplace confidentiality).

```
    const credentialsStub: AWS.ChainableTemporaryCredentials = JSON.parse(
       `actual value replaced`
    );

    const sinonStub = sinon.stub(awsIAM, 'getCredentials');
    sinonStub.resolves(credentialsStub);
```

However, when I try to run the test, I get an error saying that `obj.getPromise()` is not a function, which I guess makes some sense because getPromise() method was not specified in the string which I used to make the `credentialsStub`, but it is definitely a method that the `ChainableTemporaryCredentials` class can use (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ChainableTemporaryCredentials.html). Would anyone know how to correctly stub/spy the `getPromise` method, or in general stub/spy a method of a returned object that itself is being stubbed?

Comment: You should create a minimal, reproducible example. Can't helper without enough code

Comment: From what I understand, `awsIAM.getCredentials` needs to resolve to an object with a `getPromise` member which is a function which returns a Promise. I'm not sure what the `JSON.parse` call returns, but it definitely will not be an object with a `getPromise` function. So why not set the value of `credentialsStub` to an appropriate object?